# Problem in displaying related objects in template for detail view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to render every {{ episode.object }} in single video.html page where  it works fine for {{ video.object }}. But it isn't showing anything for episode object.. The final template video.html that I want to render episode objects can be seen here https://ibb.co/K9NMXtS
I tried

```
{% for episode in episodes %}
  {{ episode.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

But that didn't worked. Here is the other configurations:-

```
#models.py
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    trailer = models.URLField(default='')

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
    

def get_absolute_url(self):
    from django.urls import reverse

    return reverse("video.html", kwargs={"slug": str(self.slug)})


class Episode(models.Model):
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, related_name='episodes', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    air_date = models.DateField()
    videolink = models.URLField(default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('video/<slug>/', views.VideoDetail.as_view(), name='videos'),
]

# view.py
class VideoDetail(DetailView):
    model = Video
    template_name = 'video/video.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
       context = super().get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
       context['Episodes'] = Episode.objects.all()
       return context
```

Comment: What do you want `/video/my-slug/` to display? A `DetailView` fetches a single item from the database, but there might be two (or more) episodes which link to that video.

Comment: I think that maybe you should set `model = Video` in the `DetailView`, and then the real question is how do you display the episodes for that video in the template.

Comment: I want to fetch all episode on single template with help of DetailView

Comment: But as I said, `DetailView` is for a single object, so first you need to set `model = Video` so that the view fetches the single video with that slug. Your question is about using a slug with a foreign key, but that's the wrong problem.

Comment: if I set model= Video I Can't use {{ episodes.title }} in template without for loop

Comment: There can be 0, 1, or more episodes for each video. So it isn't possible to use `episode.title` unless you use a for loop (or say, use the first episode with `episode = episodes[0]`).

Comment: If you trust me, set `model = Video`, and update your question to describe your problem, 
then I can help. But as I've tried to explain, a `DetailView` with `model = Episode` using `episode.video.slug` as the slug isn't going to work, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: Ok .. I will update the question again Thank you

Comment: I have updated the post question see if you can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python and Django templates are case sensitive. You use `Episodes` in the view, which doesn't match `episodes` in the template. Change one of them so that it matches (`episodes` is recommended for model instances in Python/Django).

Next, you are using `Episode.objects.all()` at the moment, which will display *all* episodes. If you only want the episodes for that video, then filter the queryset:

```
context['episodes'] = Episode.objects.filter(video=self.object)
```

Or you can get the same result by following the foreign key backwards:

```
context['episodes'] = self.object.episodes.all()
```

Comment: Ok now , episode.object is rendering But It is also displaying  other episodes title which is in other Video title..I want it to display only episode of particular Video title..How can I do it.

Comment: It sounds like you need to use `Episode.filter(video=self.object)` or `self.object.episodes.all()` like in my answer.

Comment: Oh! my bad I forgot to change it.. After changes it is working fine  Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

add VideoDetail, self in super tag
and while calling in template  `{{  episode.video.slug  }}`
and slug enough in url

```
path('video/<slug>/', views.VideoDetail.as_view(), name='videos'),
```

class VideoDetail(DetailView):
model = Episode
template_name = 'video/video.html'

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
   context = super(VideoDetail, self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
   context['Episodes'] = Episode.objects.all()
   return context
```

Comment: didn't work still giving the error Cannot resolve keyword 'slug' into field. Choices are: air_date,

Comment: can you please explain in detail and include where the error is showing and include template file it will help for solve your problem or else give a github link

Comment: I am not trying to get video.slug in template..It's just when I go to video.html then the error is displayed because there is no slug field in Episode model

Comment: ohh ! i understood when we are using detail view we have to include a slugfiled in model or just pass primary key instead of slug

Comment: just replace <slug:slug> with <int:pk> or just '<pk>/'

Comment: it will definetely work let me know any error is displaying

Comment: No, I want to use slug from Video model which is connected to video object in Episode model with ForeignKey

Comment: it is not possible just add slug field to Episode model as foreign key to video                         ---slug= models.ForeignKey('Video.slug', on_delete=models.CASCADE)----  is this helpful for you

Comment: that's why I posted this to find if there is another way through it without changing Episode model

Comment: the way you are  creating new slug in Episode model will give error as we can't use 'Video.slug' in foreignkey it should be name of model only.

Comment: try this one slug= models.ForeignKey(Video, to_field='slug')

Comment: if this also giving errors there is small problem somewhere else in the django code let me share the github link i will test on computer and i will give you the correct code

Comment: It is giving error while running python manage.py migrate

Comment: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'video_episode' with primary key '1' has an invalid foreign key: video_episode.slug_id contains a value '' that does not have a corresponding value in video_video.slug.

Comment: go to admin page give slug value to all video objects and replace <int:pk> in url to <slug>

Comment: That won't work without migrate there is error OperationalError at /admin/video/episode/

no such column: video_episode.slug_id

Comment: it's enough if you give me the project file github or gdrive link i will fix otherwise you can try